# view dataexport xml file

Tags: datetime, importing-exporting

I am trying to export a date field as mm/dd/yyyy.  I keep getting the time 0:00:00 added on the end.  Can someone tell me how to format the output from within the view.
Formatter: choices are Date and time, Time ago, and plain.  I chose date and time.
Choose how users view dates and times:  we have one format which is called:
News item (04/17/2015) which is perfect except that the output includes the time.
What can I do from within the view to omit the time?
thanks